# bitcode bundle could not be generated because

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

Basically I have built a compiled released framework and distributed it with cocoaPods. The problem is that then archiving this framework application gets the following error:
[image]

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '/Users/cagrialtay/Desktop/mucbirsebepler/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Flutter'
>   was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode
>   must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file
>   '/Users/cagrialtay/Desktop/mucbirsebepler/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Flutter'
>   for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Search for Enable Bitcode setting
>   and set it to YES for Debug and Release modes.

Things I tried but had no luck

- Enable Bitcode' set to 'YES' Adding '-fembed-bitcode' to 'Other C
- Flags' Adding 'BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE' with the value 'bitcode' set
- skip install to yes

I only need release version, so I did not built an universal framework, just release version... I would genuinely like to solve this issue, because it has been a nightmare for me..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I finally solved this.This error happened because of me . I develop my iOS application with flutter, so if you develop your iOS app in Flutter firstly you must build with flutter not Xcode

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios
```

then go

> Xcode -> Product -> Destination -> Any iOS Device
>
> Xcode-> Product -> Scheme -> choose scheme -> Runner
>
> Xcode-> Product -> Archive

or

```
flutter clean
flutter build ipa
```

then

> Xcode-> Product -> Archive

Comment: Thanks for the instruction list, as a someone who's not familiar with iOS development, I always forget the steps :D

Answer (score 1):

That happened to me too. Xcode 11, Flutter. I tried deleting the App on Simulator still did not work.

1. Open project folder
2. Go to ios file
3. Go to Runner Folder
4. Right click on "Launch Screen.storyboard"
5. Open with Xcode.